# asp.net identity 2 bearer token authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, bearer-token

I am trying figure out where the bearer token in asp.net identity is actually deciphered and confirmed.

I would like to get into that pipeline so that I can populate an IAuthenticatedUser Singleton that lives in IOC container.  I can populate this in process of logging in with credentials, but I want to populate that again when authenticated with bearer token.

Comment: The action takes place in the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.oauth.oauthauthorizationserverprovider(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Yes that is true and it is initially where I had the logic the populated the ICurrentUser with the details i wanted to inject into the application stack.  Reading through the OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider I didn't see a method that handled the grant type for bearer token.  I did see OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Class and this might provide me that step im looking for.   I placed that logic in the base class controller class if i remember correctly, but i will revisit it when i get a chance.